# Incomplete or corrupt PNG file - svg tag to pdf using jsPDf in React application

Tags: svg, jspdf, recharts

I want to convert svg image tag to an image in PDF using jsPDF (in frontend React application). I an getting all console.log statements to verify all variables are as per the needed (string/base64). However this is gives me `Incomplete or corrupt PNG file` at the last line of this code. Can anybody please help me know why is this causing it...??

```
let serializer = new XMLSerializer()
let chartItem = serializer.serializeToString(document.getElementsByClassName("recharts-surface")[0])
console.log(chartItem)
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log(context)
let v = await Canvg.from(context, chartItem)
console.log(v)
let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
console.log(img)
doc.addImage(chartItem, 'PNG', 20, 200, 200, 100)
```

Comment: shouldn't you be passing img to doc.addImage rather than chartItem?

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson for pointing my mistake.
But now I just get a black image with jpeg and with png it is blank (or may be white box)...

Comment: To get any further we'd need to know what document.getElementsByClassName("recharts-surface")[0] is i.e. what is it's value. Does it have a root <svg> element with width and height attributes that are not percentages.

Comment: The screenshot of document.getElementsByClassName("recharts-surface")[0] is [here](https://github.com/solelthermtechnik/jspdfissues/blob/main/Screen%20Shot%202021-02-12%20at%205.59.42%20PM.png) and the element in string format is [here](https://github.com/solelthermtechnik/jspdfissues/blob/main/svgelement)

Comment: Finally was successful. Used `html2canvas` to write to canvas and then same `doc.addImage` method.